# Google Places are not Showing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services

I have referred from this tutorial [Android – AutoCompleteTextView with Google Places Autocomplete API](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/#comment-906863)  but it is not showing places when I type in the autocompleteTextView . I have tried with browser key(as written) and with android key but doesn't find a solution and unable to view places... HELP

Edited : Logcat Error `Result = {   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 103.240.236.65, with empty referer",   "predictions" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}`

Comment: Make sure you enable the api in the developer console. I suggest you follow through the steps in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/auth).

Answer (score 0):

**found !**

1. go to google console https://console.developers.google.com/
2. enable this api " Google Places Api For Web Service"
3. crate Server key(yes, server key).
4. in the input click on it and leave it blank [the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM40q.png)
5. take the key and use it like this

   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.7463956,-73.9852992&radius=100&key=your_key_here

**hope its help :)**